# Lotus Notes Error on mac

Tags: mac, lotus-notes

On Mac when i try to open a document from a database it givesc me "Error in loading DLL"
Please note that is not on the mail database.
I have some script on the "Declaration" Object of the form that the document i try to open is made with.

Comment: Does the document have embedded objects in it? Or customised database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the developer used some Windows- specific DLL- functions in this application. 
The code in the Declaration- section then looks similar to this:

```
Declare Sub tapiRequestMakeCall Lib "TAPI32" (Byval lpszDestAddress$,Byval lpszAppName$, 
  Byval lpszCalledParty$, Byval lpszComment$)
```

Please contact the developer of the application to either

a) remove the Windows- specific code

b) give you a version that is compatible with MAC

Comment: the code is this :Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (Byval bVk As Integer, Byval bScan As Integer, Byval dwflags As Long, Byval dwextrainfo As Long)
Const VK_F6 = &H75
Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2

Comment: The developer uses the user32.dll to Emulate Key- presses... This is only working on Windows... That is the reason for your error.